# Activating the Android 5 native SIP client

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, voip, sip

Android brought a native SIP client with version 2.3, which some carriers/phone manufacturers disabled. You can [re-enable it](http://www.android-hilfe.de/thema/sip-client-verwenden.477229/) in Android 4 by setting some values in `/system/build.prop`.

I do have a Android 5 phone (Wiko Rainbow UP), and there are no SIP settings in sight. [`build.prop`](https://www.droidwiki.de/Build.prop) does not contain the

```
ro.config.hw_support_ipcall=true
ro.config.hide_sipcall=false
```

settings.

How can I enable the native VoIP client on Android 5?

Comment: have you tried adding the lines manually?